# Ant: How to set Environment Variables Using Ant

Tags: ant

I have environment variables in a file called release.com as follows,

```
echo "<<< OpenSplice HDE Release V5.5.1OSS For x86.linux2.6, Date 2012-05-23 >>>"
if [ "$SPLICE_ORB" = "" ]
then
    SPLICE_ORB=DDS_OpenFusion_1_6_1
    export SPLICE_ORB
fi
if [ "$SPLICE_JDK" = "" ]
then
    SPLICE_JDK=jdk
    export SPLICE_JDK
fi
OSPL_HOME="/usr/local/covidien/HDE/x86.linux2.6"
OSPL_TARGET=x86.linux2.6
PATH=$OSPL_HOME/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OSPL_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CPATH=$OSPL_HOME/include:$OSPL_HOME/include/sys:$CPATH
OSPL_TMPL_PATH=$OSPL_HOME/etc/idlpp
OSPL_URI=file://$OSPL_HOME/etc/config/ospl.xml
. $OSPL_HOME/etc/java/defs.$SPLICE_JDK
CLASSPATH=$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj.jar:$CLASSPATH
CLASSPATH=$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpscj.jar:$CLASSPATH
export CLASSPATH OSPL_HOME OSPL_TARGET PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH CPATH OSPL_TMPL_PATH OSPL_URI
$@
```

and i will use this environment variables in Linux as,

```
# source release.com
```

Using **Ant script** how to set `release.com` as source ?

Comment: I think you need to provide a little more context: 1) what are you trying to achieve? 2) What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mark's answer, Ant XML build files may also be used to centralize your dependencies in external files.

**dependencies.xml**

```
<project name="deps" basedir=".">  
  <dirname property="deps.basedir" file="${ant.file.deps}"/>

  <property name="my.jar" location="${deps.basedir}/my-tasks.jar" />

  <taskdef name="my-ant-task" classpath="${my.jar}"
      classname="org.my.domain.ant.MyAmazingTask" />
</project>
```

**build.xml**

```
<project name="my-project" basedir=".">
  <import file="dependencies.xml" />

  <target name="give-my-task-a-spin">
    <my-ant-task />
  </target>
</project>
```

If you have a large number of custom tasks, it a good idea to place them in an antlib, which can reduce memory usage by sharing the same class loader for all the tasks in the library.

```
<antlib>
  <taskdef name="my-task01"
      classname="org.my.domain.ant.MyCustomTask01" />

  <taskdef name="my-task02"
      classname="org.my.domain.ant.MyCustomTask02" />

  <taskdef name="my-task03"
      classname="org.my.domain.ant.MyCustomTask03" />

  ...

</antlib>
```

Comment: For managing ANT dependencies I'd recommend Apache ivy: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/

Comment: Apache Ivy is definitely good for managing Ant dependencies. However, for simple external Ant config files, using a project file instead of a Java properties file has the advantage of not only allowing for simple key-value pairs (in the form of properties), but also enables creating small libraries of macrodefs, typedefs, etc.

Comment: While I fully understand the argument for multiple build files, I'm not a fan.. It works fine in the beginning but over time your projects become more and more tightly coupled with each other (via the shared build logic)... My radical opinion is that if build logic is truly re-usable then it should be packaged as an antlib and distributed as an ivy managed jar. This introduces the ability to version the common logic, enabling projects to innovate without breaking older builds.

Comment: I agree. When I first started using Ant, I was attempting to reuse build logic via macrodefs bundled in build files. I quickly came to the conclusion that shared build logic is best handled by writing custom Ant tasks packaged in antlibs and distributed as jars. However, until now, I have not distributed the jars via Ivy. I think I will following your suggestion and start using Ivy. Thanks Mark!